# Mathematica: how to find the max of an expression with exponents as parameters

Tags: optimization, statistics, wolfram-mathematica, probability

I'm using Mathematica 8 to find an analytic solution to the max of an expression.  When I use the Maximize command to try to find a solution, it just repeats what I entered, implying that Mathematica doesn't know how to do it.  I've narrowed down the problem to this: it seems like if there is an exponent that is a parameter, Maximize doesn't work.  Here's an example.  This is the likelihood function from a Bernoulli trial, where a and b are the successes and failures.

```
Maximize[{t^a*(1 - t)^b, {t >= 0, t <= 1, a > 0, b > 0}}, {t}]
```

What I would like to get as a solution is `a/(a+b)` in this case.  If I provide constants like 3 and 2 instead of `a` and `b` then it finds the solution.

Is there a different way to specify the expression or the constraints so that Mathematica can find a maximum to expressions with exponents that are parameters?  I feel like there's something I'm missing because this is so simple.

Comment: Apparently Mma can't solve this easier one `Maximize[{t^a*(1 - t), 0 < t < 1 && a > 0 }, t]`

Comment: @belisarius, it's very odd as it is easily solved via the first derivative method.

Comment: @rcollyer Yeap. I think there is still a gap between analytical and algebraic methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been playing with it, i.e. moving conditions, changing expression form, removing conditions, and I can't get `Maximize` to behave, either. However, this can be solved directly, as follows

```
Solve[ D[ t^a (1 - t)^b, t ] == 0, t]
```

which gives, as you said, `{{t -> a/(a + b)}}`. Sometimes [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html) can be used to help understand why a function like `Maximize` misbehaves by giving a more complete picture of the solution space.  It is invoked like `Solve`, as follows

```
Reduce[ D[ t^a (1 - t)^b, t ] == 0, t]
```

giving

```
((-1 + t) t != 0 && a == 0 && b == 0) || 
 (a + b != 0 && a b != 0 && t == a/(a + b)) || 
 (Re[b] > 1 && t == 1) || 
 (Re[a] > 1 && t == 0)
```

which isn't all that helpful, in this case.

Comment: Using your approach, I tried adding the constraints to the Reduce command and Mathematica has basically hung.  I would think the constraints should help it along by eliminating useless paths, but maybe it doesn't work that way.

`Reduce[{D[t^a*(1 - t)^b, t] == 0, t >= 0, t <= 1, a > 0, b > 0, 
  D[t^a*(1 - t)^b, {t, 2}] < 0}, t]`

Comment: @Sam, instead of putting them in a list, separate them with an `&&`, e.g. this is what I have `Reduce[D[t^a (1 - t)^b, t] == 0 && a > 0 && b > 0 && 0 <= t <= 1, t]`, and it works fine.

Comment: @Sam, also, as you can see, the conditions are not strictly necessary as the solution you were looking for was already present in the list. Adding the conditions merely provides the points on the boundaries.

Comment: Belated thanks for your help.

It's funny how calculus still comes in handy even when we have tools like Mathematica.

Comment: @Sam you're welcome. Calculus is just another tool, also, so it pays to have several different tools available.

Answer (score 1):

The Maximize function in Mathematica, applied on an exponential function, only works if you maximize with respect to all parameters (a, b and t in your case). Now, you only maximize with respect to t, which does not work.

Consider this easy example (using Mathematica 8.0):

```
Maximize[{Exp[a + b], a <= 1, b <= 1}, {a, b}]
Maximize[{Exp[a + b], a <= 1, b <= 1}, {a}]
Maximize[{a + b, a <= 1, b <= 1}, {a}]
```

Comment: This would be more illustrative if you showed the results of each of these commands.  If you were feeling especially nice, [you could even link to the Wolfram Alpha results](http://tinyurl.com/cuj5a93).

Comment: It would be great if a and b could be chosen arbitrarily, but they are constants.  It's unfortunate it doesn't work with respect to just t.